# Solution for Summation of $\cos^2x$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

Can you give me the solution for the summation 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos^2(\pi n)
$$

---

Edit: Please give me the explanation of how it is calculated and also final answer in integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you noticed out the terms behaved? $\cos(\pi n) = (-1)^n$, so $\cos^2(\pi n) = 1$. This series is just summing a bunch of ones, so it diverges.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Won't it care about the summations and the limits?

Comment: @Gowtham: If every term is $1$ till infinity, is the summation defined(does it converge)?

Comment: But in my text it is given as N+1 when it is preceded by $ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty }$

Comment: @Gowtham : The summation goes to $+\infty$. This because 
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \cos^2(\pi n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1 = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N 1 = \lim_{N \to \infty} (N+1). 
$$
Is everything okay?

Comment: Yeah @PatrickDaSilva